# Need to replace OS drive on ubuntu system, how do i keep soft-raid partition?

Tags: ubuntu, raid, software-raid

So right now I have a HTPC with 5 drives in it.   One drive is an OS drive (mounted on /) that is starting to fail, SMART is telling me continually that I have bad sectors.   The other drives are 4 drives in a Software-Raid5 array setup by the "disk manager" tool within ubuntu.

If i format the OS drive, will the new OS properly see the raid5 Array, is there anything i should backup for mdadmin to see this raid5 array properly?  Backing up is something I plan on doing before re-installing the OS (can't ever be too safe) but if i can replace the OS drive & re-install Ubuntu without having to restore all my music & recorded TV I would really like to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turned out to be easier to just backup & reinstall.